# Is there a way to migrate previous build from testflight to itunesconnect before the shutdown?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

Is there a way to migrate previous builds from testflight to itunesconnect before the shutdown?

Answer (score 1):

Not that i am aware of... just peoples (contacts). you will have to check your builds history (organizer) and  upload the one you want manually.

Comment: thanks.. never thought about the organiizer.. but then do u think the builds on testflight will be rendered inactive after the shutdown?

Comment: looks like it. no new downloads will be possible.